# What are the required properties within each object in the results array for this curl request?

Tags: javascript, json, curl, fetch, javascript-objects

I'm currently working on a JavaScript coding assessment and I'm having trouble understanding the expected format for the request body when using the Fetch API. The API documentation states that it accepts results in JSON format and returns an HTTP 200 response if the data is correct.

Here is the cURL command provided that I have to use and get the result while replacing it with the fetch request shown below.

this is the given Curl:

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://switch-yam-equator.azurewebsites.net/api/validation \
--header 'x-chmura-cors: <access_token>' \
 --data '<results>'
```

this is whatI'mm using now.

```
fetch('https://switch-yam-equator.azurewebsites.net/api/validation', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-chmura-cors': '3d088e34-eda0-4f33-a114-b7345c5c5fa9',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "Name": "",
    "KRMovies": [],
    "NCMovies": [],
    "actorId": actorId
  })
})
```

and this should be the response:

so I got the matching actorId's but just need to get the validation result.

Comment: It’s not clear what the issue or question is.